# Proof n-cube graph is connected

Tags: graph-theory

I am studying graph theory and my text book gives a proof for an n-cube graph being connected that I find really weird/confusing. Is there a simpler proof to show that the n-cube is connected.

The n-cube graph is the graph where the vertices {0,1} strings of length n. Two strings are adjacent if they differ is exactly one position.

For example the 2-cube graph has vertices V:{00, 01, 10, 11} and edges: 
(00 <-> 01),
(00 <-> 10),
(01 <-> 11),
(10 <-> 11)

This is simply a square. What kind of proof can I use show that it is connected? I am currently thinking induction.

**My rough try at a Proof**

Proof By **Induction**

Base Case ( n=1 ) 
Then graph has two vertices, 0 & 1 which are connected (since they differ by one). Assume than P(n) is true. Prove P(n+1). Lets remove the last digit. From the inductive hypothesis we know that P(n) is connected. Add the last digit back in. We can partition P(n+1) into $A_0$ which contains all the vertices with a 0 as the last digit; $A_1$ which contains all the vertices with 1 as the last digit. Since $A_0$ and $A_1$ are essentially P(n), we know they are connected from the inductive hypothesis. Since $A_0$ and $A_1$ are connected we can conclude that P(n+1) is connected!

**Is this correct?**

Comment: It would help if you could describe your textbook's proof. The way I'd do it is show that we can define the $n$-cube graph inductively from two $(n-1)$-cube graphs, then inductively show that an $n$-cube graph is connected (because there's an edge connecting the two $(n-1)$-cube graphs.)

Comment: I was writing out an inductive proof as you wrote this comment. Thanks for the insight. Is the 'rough idea of a proof' that I have provided correct?

Comment: Almost; you need to show that there's an edge connecting $A_0$ and $A_1$, too. Once you've done that, you've shown they're connected, yes.

Comment: If I show that since there exists a vertex in $A_0$ that is connected by an edge to $A_1$ because they differ by one digit(last digit) then is that enough?

Comment: Yeah.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Awesome! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a full proof as outlined above.

The $1$-cube graph is connected by inspection. (You could even do the $0$-cube graph, which is automatically connected, as it only has one vertex.) Now assume that the $n$-cube graph is connected. In the $(n+1)$-cube graph, consider the subgraphs consisting of those vertices with final digit $0$ and $1$ respectively (and all edges between them); call these $A_0$ and $A_1$. Then $A_0$ and $A_1$ are isomorphic to the $n$-cube graph, thus connected by hypothesis. Now note that there is an edge between $(0,\dots,0)$ and $(0,\dots,1)$ as they differ by a single digit.

So the $(n+1)$-cube graph is connected; for pick any vertices $p$ and $q$ in the graph. If they are both in $A_0$ or $A_1$ they are connected by inductive hypothesis; so suppose WLOG $p$ is in $A_0$ and $q$ is in $A_1$. There is a path connecting $p$ to $(0,\dots,0)$ and a path connecting $(0,\dots,1)$ to $q$ by inductive hypothesis. Connect these paths by including the edge between $(0,\dots,0)$ and $(0,\dots,1)$ and we've constructed a path connecting $p$ and $q$, as desired.

Answer (score 4):

Your proof may be correct but it is weird/confusing. There is a simpler proof that the $n$-cube is connected. A graph is connected if there is a path from any vertex to any other vertex. In terms of the $n$-cube, that just means that you can get from one $\{0,1\}$-string of length $n$ to another one by changing one bit at a time. Which is so obvious that there is no point in writing a detailed proof.

Comment: Amusingly this much more clear way of doing things is precisely the inductive proof given in my answer, which somewhat obfuscates what's going on.

Comment: Yeah, that's when I thought when I read the answer, it seemed incredibly obvious. I wonder what it is that makes things so obvious after a while.

Comment: @MikeMiller A more interesting approach would be to prove (by induction on $n$) that the $n$-cube has a [Hamiltonian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) path (a Hamiltonian *cycle* for $n\gt1$), which is of course a much stronger property than just being connected.

Comment: @Zee Out of curiosity, how does your book prove it? By the way what book is that?

Comment: @bof The book is a compiled version of course notes for a course I'm taking. It uses some convoluted logical process that keeps passing over my head. It proves that from $v_0$ (a vertex with all 0's) there exists a path to every other vertex, by x (another string with k 1's in positions 1 - j). It then iterates through each of the 1's positioned and somehow concludes that they are connected.

Answer (score 0):

proof by construction.
any two nodes, pairwise different, noted by -, if same, noted by .
then any two nodes, the difference are noted as --.--.--.--
then one is --0--1--0--1--, the other is --1--0--1--0--
then there is edges between
between --0--1--0--1-- and --1--1--0--1--
between --1--1--0--1-- and --1--0--0--1--
between --1--0--0--1-- and --1--0--1--1--
between --1--0--1--1-- and --1--0--1--0--
then there is a path betwen --0--1--0--1-- and --1--0--1--0--

so, there is path between any two node, so graph is connected.